# Token based authentication using Authentication header giving 403 forbidden error

Tags: reactjs, django, django-rest-framework, fetch, django-rest-auth

### I have the following code in my react app:

I am sending an update request to rest backed which requires a user to be authenticated to perform PUT/POST/DELETE requests.

```js
const update = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault()
  const formData = new FormData(form.current);
  console.log('Token ' + localStorage.getItem("token")) // valid token
  const requestOptions = {
    method: 'PUT',
    headers : {
      // 'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa('user:password') // basic authentication works
      "Authorization": 'Token ' + localStorage.getItem("token"),
    },
    body: formData
  };
    
  fetch(url, requestOptions)
    .then(async response => {
      const data = await response.json();
      if(!response.ok){
        const error = (data && data.message ) || response.status;
        return Promise.reject(error)
      }
      alert('member updated')
      history.push("/members")
    })
    .catch(error => console.error('Some error ', error))
  }
```

Unfortunately, I'm getting these in console logs:

```
PUT http://localhost:8000/uskindia/56/ 403 (Forbidden)
Some error  403
```

And this in backed logs:

```
Forbidden: /uskindia/56/
[... *:*:*] "PUT /uskindia/56/ HTTP/1.1" 403 58
```

Trying to solve this for the last 24 hours but not getting it right.

### From various tries, it seems like:

- backend DRF and django-rest-auth is not handling token properly
- tried various user agents like curl, httpie and postman to view request and response closely
- Even in backed put logs, but `request.user == AnonymousUser` with token based authorisation.
- works well with basic authorizatin, scheme.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using djangorestframework for backend you must send token with this format :

`"Authorization": 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem("token"),`

use Bearer instead of token.

Comment: From docs it is recommended to use `"Authorization": 'Token ' + localStorage.getItem("token"),` but there is some issue, need to debug it thoroughly.

Comment: which library you are using?

Comment: Django-rest-auth is used in backed along with DRF. Seems like there is something bad at backend.

Answer (score 0):

There was a typo in `settings.py`

```py
# Earlier
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASS': [
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    ],
# ....
}

# Changed to 
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    ],
# ...
}
```

Thanks to Blog by [Vitor Freitas](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/11/22/how-to-implement-token-authentication-using-django-rest-framework.html)

which made it clear that, if response contains
`WWW-Authenticaate:Token` then it means Token authentication was working.

As this was missing in my case, so I started all over setting REST_FRAMEWORK settings from scratch and found the root cause of issue.